# Testing Django throttling

Tags: python, django, testing, tastypie, throttling

I'm throttling using TastyPie, but want to add a test to make sure it's working properly. Is there an easy way to simulate 100 requests in a Django test (or hopefully some easier method) to test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend http://locust.io/, which is a great load testing tool.

If you need an automated test, you could also spawn some threads, inside of which you hit a live test server using Django's LiveServerTestCase.

If you're more concerned with the logic of your code than it's tolerance of concurrent calls, the best way might be to mock out the calls to `datetime.now()` or `time.time()` that appears in your throttle code, returning a predefined value. This let's you precisely control the conditions your throttle should act upon in a way you can't (or would be very difficult) with live concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0):

I also wrote some tests for testing the functionality of the throttling.
In general, I deactivated throttling for the tests by creating a separate `settings.py` (solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72367774/7132596) and then activated the throttling again by mocking the `get_rate` function in the throttling class that is used in the endpoint:

```py
import re
from unittest.mock import patch

from rest_framework.test import APIClient

@patch("rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle.get_rate", lambda x: "2/day")
def test_throttling():
    client = APIClient()
    for _ in range(2):
        resp = client.get("/login")
        assert resp.status_code != 429

    resp = client.get("/login")
    assert resp.status_code == 429, resp.json()
    assert re.match(r"Request was throttled. Expected available in \d+ seconds.", resp.json()["detail"])


@patch("rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle.get_rate", lambda x: "2/day")
@patch("rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle.get_rate", lambda x: "3/day")
def test_authenticated_users_not_throttled_by_anon_but_user_rate(admin_client):
    """Test that a logged-in user is not affected by the anonymous throttling, but by the user rate throttling."""
    for _ in range(3):
        resp = admin_client.get("/v1/version")
        assert resp.status_code == 200, resp.json()

    # But now the user throttling should hit
    resp = admin_client.get("/v1/version")
    assert resp.status_code == 429, resp.json()
```