# Is there a way to disable throttling while using Pytest in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pytest, throttling

**Problem:**

I want to figure out a way to disable throttling when running my tests with `pytest -vv`

**Details:**

I have this default throttling policy in my `settings.py` file:

```
  'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'anon': '100/day',
        'user': '1000/day'
    }
```

I also have this fixture in my `confest.py` which returns an error whenever I exceed the limit of requests:

```
def get_token(user, client):
    response = client.post(
        "/email-login",
        {"email":user.email, "password": "B9vX95phJDi3C4"},
    )
    return {
        "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION": f"Bearer {response.json()['token']['access']}"
    }
```

**What I have tried:**

I have attempted to use the solution in this GitHub Issue: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/1336, but it doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem with the following steps:

- I created a new settings file which inherited from the base settings file. i.e `from settings import *`
- Then I deleted the `DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES` key i.e `del REST_FRAMEWORK["DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES"]`
- Next thing I did was to point to the new settings file in `pytest.ini` i.e `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="new_settings.py"`

Now the tests will use the new settings file

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a way to differentiate between test env and otherwise. Like we do for PROD and DEV using `settings.DEBUG` config.

My recommendation is to create an env variable `test=True`and then in your `settings.py` write -

```
if os.environ.get("test", False):
   REST_FRAMEWORK = {
     'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
    'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle'
  ],
  'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
    'anon': '100/day',
    'user': '1000/day'
   }
}
```

else it does nothing, and drf will not throttle.

Answer (score 1):

@ra123 has the right idea in general.  As another approach, with all Django projects I add something like this to my `settings/__init__.py` (or just `settings.py` if you do a one file thing).  It looks at `argv` to see if its in test mode

```
IS_TESTING = bool(set(sys.argv[:2]) & {"pytest", "test", "jenkins"})

REST_FRAMEWORK = { "YOUR_CONFIG": "..." }

# at the very very end, AFTER your settings are loaded:
if IS_TESTING:
    # override your rest framework settings in test mode
    REST_FRAMEWORK["DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES"] = []

    # some other handy things, for making tests faster/easier
    PASSWORD_HASHERS = ("django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher",)
    EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend"
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "inmemorystorage.InMemoryStorage"
```

I ended up with it this way so we don't have to worry about it ever getting the wrong settings.  It also helps keep things centralized, so (for example) you don't call `sentry.init` in testing mode, *even if* there is a `sentry_url` in the environment.

Comment: Thanks for this. Apparently, the new way to declare storages is this (will be removed in Django 5.1): `STORAGES = {"default": {"BACKEND": "django.core.files.storage.InMemoryStorage"}}`